# PHPExcel listWorksheetNames returns Empty

Tags: phpexcel

The code below is returning an empty sheets array for at least two different .xlsx files (from the same source), although for other .xls and .xlsx it does return an filled array.

$inputFileType  is valid" EXCEL2007", $path is valid and there are sheets in the file. var_dump on $objReader display an object.

Any ideas?

```
public function listSheets($path)
    {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($path);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $sheets = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($path);
        return $sheets;
    }
```

**Update**
The function listWorkBookInfo also fails for the same files that listWorkBookNames fails.

The workbook xml are different. Theses xmk are outut from

```
$this->getFromZipArchive($zip, "{$rel['Target']}")
```

*PHPExcel likes*

```
<workbook xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:ignorable="x15" xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main"><fileversion appname="xl" lastedited="6" lowestedited="4" rupbuild="14420"><workbookpr defaultthemeversion="124226"><mc:alternatecontent xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"><mc:choice requires="x15"><x15ac:abspath url="W:\Rates\carrier\" xmlns:x15ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac"></x15ac:abspath></mc:choice></mc:alternatecontent><bookviews><workbookview xwindow="0" ywindow="0" windowwidth="21570" windowheight="8145"></workbookview></bookviews><sheets><sheet name="Rates" sheetid="1" r:id="rId1"><sheet name="Data" sheetid="4" state="hidden" r:id="rId2"></sheet></sheet></sheets><calcpr calcid="152511"></calcpr></workbookpr></fileversion></workbook>
```

and *PHPExcel does not likes*

```
<x:workbook xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><x:fileversion appname="xl" lastedited="5" lowestedited="5" rupbuild="9303"><x:workbookpr defaultthemeversion="124226"><x:bookviews><x:workbookview xwindow="360" ywindow="45" windowwidth="10515" windowheight="7245"></x:workbookview></x:bookviews><x:sheets><x:sheet name="International Destinations" sheetid="5" r:id="rId1"><x:sheet name="National Destinations" sheetid="4" r:id="rId2"></x:sheet></x:sheet></x:sheets><x:calcpr calcid="145621"></x:calcpr></x:workbookpr></x:fileversion></x:workbook>
```

Comment: Well if it works for some but not for others, all we can really do is guess that there's something different about those that it doesn't work for.... otherwise the crystal ball is a little bit cloudy today

Comment: No, PHPExcel doesn't like different namespacing to that which MS Excel uses when it creates files

Comment: It just seems odd that some files from the same source should use namespacing and others don't